# How to pass env variable to remote host using publish over ssh in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, remote-server

I am using publish over ssh plugin in Jenkins to connect to my application host to deploy the application.

I am fetching DB credentials from vault and passed to remote host using sshPublisher()

(https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin).

However, the variable passed say $username, is showing as blank in remote host.

I am using something like below:

```
withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: 'Id',
usernameVariable: 'username', passwordVariable: 'password']]) {
sshPublisher(
    publishers: [
        sshPublisherDesc(
            configName: 'DevHost', transfers: [
                sshTransfer(
                    cleanRemote: false, excludes: '', execCommand: '. /deploy.sh dev', 
                    execTimeout: 120000, flatten: false, makeEmptyDirs: false, noDefaultExcludes: false, patternSeparator: '[, ]+', 
                    remoteDirectory: '/app/dev', remoteDirectorySDF: false, removePrefix: '', sourceFiles: ''
                )
            ], 
            usePromotionTimestamp: false, useWorkspaceInPromotion: false, verbose: false)
        ]
    )
```

Here username and password are used inside deploy.sh, but both are NULL